# Calibrating Probabilities in lightgbm or XGBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, lightgbm

Hi i need help in calibrating probabilities in lightgbm

below is my code

cv_results = lgb.cv(params, 
                    lgtrain, 
                    nfold=10,
                    stratified=False ,
                    num_boost_round = num_rounds,
                    verbose_eval=10,
                    early_stopping_rounds = 50, 
                    seed = 50)

best_nrounds = cv_results.shape[0] - 1

lgb_clf = lgb.train(params, 
                    lgtrain, 
                    num_boost_round=10000 ,
                    valid_sets=[lgtrain,lgvalid],
                    early_stopping_rounds=50,
                    verbose_eval=10)

ypred = lgb_clf.predict(test, num_iteration=lgb_clf.best_iteration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about LighGBM, but in the case of XGBoost, if you want to calibrate the probabilities the best and most probably the only way is to **use CalibratedClassifierCV from sklearn**.

You can find it here - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html

The only catch here is that **the CalibratedClassifierCV only takes sklearn's estimators as input**, so you might have to use the sklearn wrapper for XGBoost instead of the traditional XGBoost API's .train function.

You can find the XGBoost's sklearn wrapper here - https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier

I hope it answers your question.

Comment: No, any calibration by scikit-learn will distort the probabilities generated by XGBoost. Both isotonic and sigmoid calibration will make the results worse in every respect.

Comment: I’ve got a case and been trying infinitely to improve probabilities from XGBoost using calibrated classifier cv.

Every single test is telling me that this is not going anywhere when it comes to XGBoost...

If someone has any idea why, I’d be very happy if you can tell me.

I was expecting that it wouldn’t give me a perfect calibration, but not deteriorate my already not so happy calibrations.

Comment: @MarkConway On what basis / care to expand?